# $\frac{1}{z^2}$ is holomorphic

Tags: complex-analysis, analyticity

> I have to show that $z\mapsto\frac1{z^2}$ is holomorpic on $\mathbb C\setminus\{0\}$ and compute its $n$-th derivative

I know that $\frac{1}{z^2}=\sum\limits_{n\ge0}(-1)^n(n+1)(z-1)^n$, so it has a power series representation. Is that sufficient to conclude that the function is analytic, which is stronger than holomorphic. I thought analytic means inifinitely differentiable and holomorphic only continuously differentiable, how can one then compute $n$-th derivative of a holomorphic function, if $n$ is greater than $1$? However I computed it;

$\left(\frac{1}{z^2}\right)^{(n)}=\sum\limits_{k\ge n}(-1)^k(n+1)n!(z-1)^{k-n}$ is that correct ?

Comment: Both holomorphic and analytic are conditions that are a lot stronger than infinitely continuously differentiable. To check that it is holomorphic, use the Cauchy-Riemann equations.

Comment: @Arthur Yes this shows differentiability, but not $n$ times, and how would you compute it ?

Comment: @derivative: Your proposed series converges (only) on a disk of finite radius, so all other considerations aside your solution is incomplete. As Arthur says, checking the Cauchy-Riemann equations (or better, using theorems about holomorphic functions, e.g., do you know anything about a quotient of holomorphic functions?) is easier than using power series. To calculate the $n$th derivative, just use the power rule from calculus.

Comment: Incidentally, a complex-valued function $f$ defined in some non-empty open subset $D$ of $\mathbf{C}$ is _analytic_ if at each point $z_{0}$ of $D$, there exists a power series representation of $f$ in some disk centered at $z_{0}$; $f$ is _holomorphic_ in $D$ if $f$ satisfies the Cauchy-Riemann equations at each point of $D$. Remarkably, these two conditions are equivalent (even though _a priori_ being analytic looks much stronger than being holomorphic).

Comment: @user86418 The problem was the derivative, if the power rule is also applicable in the complex case, then is should be OK

Comment: @Arthur Goursat's theorem: if a complex function is defined on an open set of the complexe and is differentiable at any point, then it is holomorphic in the open set. Continuity of the derivative is not necessary (but is a consequence). For complex functions (on an open set), differentiability is equivalent to being analytic (or holomorphic).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given$$f(z) = {z^{ - 2}}$$
then, for$$z = x + iy$$
we may write$$f(x + iy) = \frac{{{x^2} - {y^2}}}{{{{({x^2} + {y^2})}^2}}} + i\frac{{ - 2xy}}{{{{({x^2} + {y^2})}^2}}}$$
For$$\begin{gathered}
  u(x,y) = \frac{{{x^2} - {y^2}}}{{{{({x^2} + {y^2})}^2}}} \hfill \\
  v(x,y) = \frac{{ - 2xy}}{{{{({x^2} + {y^2})}^2}}} \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered}$$
Cauchy-Riemann Equations are satisfied.

For n-th order derivative, we get for $n \in \mathbb{N}$:
$$\frac{{{d^n}f}}{{d{z^n}}}(z) = \left\{ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
  {{{( - 1)}^{2n - 1}}(2n)! \cdot z \cdot f{{(z)}^{2n - 1}}} \\ 
  {{{( - 1)}^{2n}}(2n + 1)!f{{(z)}^{2n - 1}}} 
\end{array}} \right.$$

One gets this by carefully calculating:
$$\begin{gathered}
  \frac{{df}}{{d{z^1}}}(z) = {( - 1)^1} \cdot 2! \cdot z \cdot f{(z)^2} \hfill \\
  \frac{{{d^3}f}}{{d{z^3}}}(z) = {( - 1)^3} \cdot 4! \cdot z \cdot f{(z)^3} \hfill \\
  \frac{{{d^5}f}}{{d{z^5}}}(z) = {( - 1)^5} \cdot 6! \cdot z \cdot f{(z)^4} \hfill \\
   \vdots  \hfill \\
   \hfill \\
  \frac{{{d^2}f}}{{d{z^2}}}(z) = 3! \cdot f{(z)^2} \hfill \\
  \frac{{{d^4}f}}{{d{z^4}}}(z) = 5! \cdot f{(z)^3} \hfill \\
  \frac{{{d^6}f}}{{d{z^6}}}(z) = 7! \cdot f{(z)^4} \hfill \\
   \vdots  \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered}$$

Comment: thank you very much but then is the derivative $\frac{d^nf}{dz^n}(z)=(-1)^n(n+1)! z^{-2-n}$ in general, what do you have there in the middle with left brace ?

Comment: Just splitted in even and odd order of derivative. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

If we know that $f(z)$ and $g(z)$ have complex derivatives at $z=z_0$, then
$$
\begin{align}
&\lim_{z\to z_0}\frac{f(z)g(z)-f(z_0)g(z_0)}{z-z_0}\\
&=\lim_{z\to z_0}\frac{f(z)g(z)-f(z)g(z_0)+f(z)g(z_0)-f(z_0)g(z_0)}{z-z_0}\\
&=\lim_{z\to z_0}\frac{f(z)g(z)-f(z)g(z_0)}{z-z_0}
+\lim_{z\to z_0}\frac{f(z)g(z_0)-f(z_0)g(z_0)}{z-z_0}\\
&=\lim_{z\to z_0}f(z)\frac{g(z)-g(z_0)}{z-z_0}
+g(z_0)\lim_{z\to z_0}\frac{f(z)-f(z_0)}{z-z_0}\\[6pt]
&=f(z_0)g'(z_0)+f'(z_0)g(z_0)\tag{1}
\end{align}
$$

Using $(1)$, $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}z}1=\lim\limits_{z\to z_0}\frac{1-1}{z-z_0}=0$, $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}z}z=\lim\limits_{z\to z_0}\frac{z-z_0}{z-z_0}=1$,  and induction, we get for $n\ge0$
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}z}z^n=nz^{n-1}\tag{2}
$$
If we know that $f(z)$ has a complex derivative at $z=z_0$ and that $f(z_0)\ne0$, then
$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{z\to z_0}\frac{\frac1{f(z)}-\frac1{f(z_0)}}{z-z_0}
&=\lim_{z\to z_0}\left[-\frac1{f(z)f(z_0)}\frac{f(z)-f(z_0)}{z-z_0}\right]\\
&=-\frac1{f(z_0)^2}f'(z_0)\tag{3}
\end{align}
$$
Thus, $1/f(z)$ also has a complex derivative at $z=z_0$.

Using $(2)$ and $(3)$, we see that we can extend $(2)$ to $n\in\mathbb{Z}$:
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}z}z^{-n}
&=-\frac1{z^{2n}}nz^{n-1}\\
&=-nz^{-n-1}\tag{4}
\end{align}
$$
Equation $(4)$ for $n=2$, says that $z^{-2}$ has a complex derivative for $z\ne0$; therefore, it is holomorphic on $\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$.

Furthermore, by induction on $(4)$, we get
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}z}z^{-2}&=-2z^{-3}\\
\frac{\mathrm{d}^2}{\mathrm{d}z^2}z^{-2}&=6z^{-4}\\
\frac{\mathrm{d}^3}{\mathrm{d}z^2}z^{-2}&=-24z^{-5}\\
&\vdots\\
\frac{\mathrm{d}^n}{\mathrm{d}z^n}z^{-2}&=(-1)^n(n+1)!\,z^{-n-2}\tag{5}
\end{align}
$$